# React - call handler from var in render function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to call an event handler from a child class that is integrated in its parent, but the handler is not being called and I also don't get any error messages.

```
var Home = React.createClass({

        handleClick: function(tableRowId, e) {
            console.log("##Clicked##", tableRowId);
        }

        render : function () {
            var tableRows = Data.map(function (tableRow) {

                    if (SelLines[tableRow.ID]) {
                        return (
                             <Tr>
                            // ...
                             <Td className = "cellSelected" column = "ACTION">  
                             // ## This doesnt call the handler
                             <a onClick = {this.handleClick.bind(this, tableRow.ID)}> {tableRow.ACTION} </ a>  <  / Td >

                             <  / Tr > )
                    } else {
                        return (
                            //...
                    };
                });
            return (
                 < div >
                 < div >
                 // ## This does work and call the handler
                 <a onClick={this.handleClick.bind(this, 1234)}> Test </a>
                 < Table className = "table" id = "table" >
                     {tableRows}
                 <  / Table >
                 <  / div >
                 <  / div > );

        }
    });
```

Comment: try set this for `.map` - `var tableRows = Data.map(function (tableRow) { //your code }, this);`

Comment: also `.map(tableRow => { // your code })` will work as well if you're transpiling or coding against modern browsers.

Comment: Tried both, but they don't change anything, the function still doesn't get triggered.

Comment: Make sure  Data is Array. It works with Array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `this` in `Data.map` doesn't refer to the React component. You need to bind `this` of React component to the callback of the `Data.map` function as well.

UPDATE : because it's difficult to perform the binding 2 levels. This is a simple way to get the `this` of React component.

```
render : function(){
  var that = this;
  ...Data.map(function(){ that.handle...})
   ....
}
```

Comment: the binding should happen to the map parameter, not to the result of map, so Data.map(function(){}.bind(this))

Comment: @Mijamo yeah! You're right ! =) I fixed it

Comment: That gives me this error: Uncaught TypeError: Data.map(...).bind is not a function

Comment: @PL I fixed the answer. Sorry ! my mistake

Comment: Almost irrelevant, but PhantomJS barfs on `function(){}.bind(this)`, it needs `(function(){}).bind(this)`

Comment: That doesn't give an error now, but it also doesn't change anything, the function still doesn't get triggered...

Comment: Sorry, that does actually work! Thanks!

Comment: @PL I updated the answer again. I hope it works for you now.

Answer (score 3):

In your map function, `this` does not refer anymore to your component, so your handler fails.

You have two solutions:

- Use [ES6 arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) to avoid this and keep this as a reference to your component, like this : `Data.map((tableRow) => {` . This would however need that you compile your code through babelify to make it compatible with current browser.
- The other solution is to declare `var c = this` before your map function and then use `c` instead of `this` in the function. this way you are sure you are actually using the component.